# Strange python script error after server migration

Tags: python

my script was working fine before migrating my server but now it gives some errors that I can't fix. It's an Ubuntu Server with Plesk control panel installed and the error message is below:

['/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage', '/tmp/tmpdoRlkR/edited.html', '/tmp/9300606835df125c28d1288.77555331.png'] Traceback (most recent call last): File "invoice_gen.py", line 140, in subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage", htmlfile, args.output]) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in **init** errread, errwrite) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have installed `/usr/bin/xvfb-run` on your new server.

I believe that's xvfb package https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/xvfb

If it doesn't work, then please try to "split" the first parameter in your command in 2 array items. Pass `'/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage'`  like `'/usr/bin/xvfb-run', '/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage'`.

So the final call should be like

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/xvfb-run", "/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage", htmlfile, args.output])
```

instead of

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage", htmlfile, args.output])
```

### The real troube solution :)

The issue was with wkhtmltoimage path! It was installed to `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage` instead of `/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage` and now it works even without xvfb!

Comment: it's installed and configured:

root@server:~# /usr/bin/xvfb-run
xvfb-run: usage error: need a command to run
Usage: xvfb-run [OPTION ...] COMMAND
Run COMMAND (usually an X client) in a virtual X server environment.
Options:
-a        --auto-servernum          try to get a free server number, starting at
                                    --server-num

Comment: Sir you rock! Your answer gave me a great idea! Thank you so much. The issue was with wkhtmltoimage path! It was installed to /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage instead of /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage and now it works even without xvfb!